# На какой рынок мобильных приложений выходить в начале?

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-8, appstore, microsoft-store

Ситуация такая, далекий провинциальный городок, работа "эникейшик-разнорабочий", зарплата минималка. Работа такая начинает очень надоедать и печалить дальнейшей перспективой.

Хочу попробовать мобильную разработку. Знания программирования ниже среднего (знаю основы ООП, пару паттернов, баловался c языками pascal, obj-c, python, ruby ), но всегда, если захотеть, можно подтянуть, благо Интернет полон курсов и книг и всего, бери, что хочешь. Главное начать.

Я абсолютно не привередлив в выборе технологии, наооброт, мне интересно практически все, это же очень круто пощупать неизвестное и известное.

Вопрос в следующем: с какого рынка мобильных приложений начать, чтобы заодно качать скил в определенном направлении и не умереть с голоду в итоге:
1) AppStore (iOS);
2) Google play (Android);
3) Windows store (WindowsPhone)?

Answer (score 2):

В принципе, не думаю, что самостоятельно, без огромных денег на пиар есть хоть какой-то шанс зарабатывать на хлеб мобильной разработкой. Потому смотрите вакансии либо фриланс, какая из платформ будет все-таки выгодней в вашем регионе.

Answer (score 1):

Рассмотрите 3 параметра:

- доля рынка;
- стоимость входа рынок;
- потенциальное количество заработка.

Не претендуя на истину в конечной инстанции, я бы расписал это так:

1. WinPhone - доля рынка <10%, порог входа минимальный (стоимость PC + аппарат), денег практически нет, но перспективы есть.
2. Android - доля рынка ~50%, порог входа минимальный: стоимость PC + аппарат, денег хватит всем.
3. iPhone - доля рынка ~40%, порог входа высокий: стоимость Mac + аппарат (~$2000), денег хватит всем и еще останутся. iPhone юзеры любят платить :)

На вашем месте я бы остановился на Android, а если есть под рукой Mac - то на iPhone.

Comment: Только стоит учесть, что под iOS, если только написать приложение и выкинуть в магазин без продвижения, велик риск, что оно пройдет незамеченным - рынок очень перенасыщен. Для Android подозреваю то же самое.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы посоветовал Вам прочесть статью на [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/194702/), очень полезно. Автор поделился своим опытом и статистикой запуска игры на iOS и Android. Единственная особенность: он выходил на русскоязычный рынок, на англоязычном, я думаю, цифры были бы другими.
Резюмируя автора, "Конечно iOS" ))))

Comment: @Bezpaliy,  резюмируя (по статье на хабре) месячные доходы в деньгах -- "овчинка не стоит выделки".

Answer (score 0):

Да какой аппарат есть в физической доступности, под такой и пишите.

Answer (score 0):

Тут уже отмечали - чтобы начать что-то делать для iOS, необходимо купить мак и несколько iOS устройств для тестирования, но если у Вас есть возможность это купить без перспективы голодать ближайшие пару месяцев - не рекомендую менять место работы. :)
А если возможности купить мак нет - вариант один - делать проект под Андроид.
Возможность заработать есть на любой платформе, заранее чураться Андроид не стоит, благодарная публика вполне может вас прокормить, если Вы дадите ей что-то любопытное, а вот с iOS просто любопытного может и не хватить.